# Simulation of Traders

Tags: simulations, price

I am writing a simulation of how traders will behave in an emergent market. The idea is to see how traders can use information from other traders to make a decisions as to whether they will buy, sell, or stay out of a market. Here is my code so far:

```
f1 <- function(n,m,priceinitial,delta,mean, sd, ninterval){
traders <- vector(mode="character", length=n)
traderscurrent <- vector(mode="character", length=n)
price <- vector(mode="numeric")
pricecurrent <- vector(mode="numeric")
for(nint in 1:ninterval)
{
  L = floor(rnorm(1,mean,sd))
  print(L)
  x3 <- runif(2,0,1)
  v <- c(0, min(x3), max(x3))
  for(i in 1:n)
  {
    traders[i] <- runif(1,0,1)
    if(findInterval(traders[i],v) == sample(c(1,3),1))
       {
         traders[i] <- "B"
       }
       else if(findInterval(traders[i],v) == 2)
               {
         traders[i] <- "N"
       }
    else {
         traders[i] <- "S"
    }
  }
  print(table(traders))
  for(step in 1:L)
  {

    for(i in 1:n)
    {
      b <- sample(traders[-i], m)
      #print(b)
      #table(b)
      traderscurrent[i] <- sample(b,1)

    }
    print(table(traderscurrent))
    pricecurrent[step] = priceinitial+length(which(traderscurrent == "B"))*delta-length(which(traderscurrent == "S"))*delta
    priceinitial = pricecurrent[step]
    traders <- traderscurrent
    #print(nint)
    #print(step)
  }
    price <- c(price,pricecurrent)
    #price <- price[-step]
    plot(price)
}
print(price)
#plot(price)

}
```

Basically we start off with $n$ traders who can look at $m < n$ others traders to make their decision. The  `priceinitial`  is updated by  `delta`  depending on the actions of the traders. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve this code/simulation?

**Note**: This simulation is written in R.

Comment: Are your "traders" live or programs?

Comment: @amdopt: They are live. I am just trying to simulate how traders behave when they have information about what other traders have done. The idea is not to predict asset prices but to simulate the psychology behind trading.

Comment: @PEV Firstly, You have 2 usernames? Secondly, having experienced this first-hand at a firm I worked for early in my career, the traders will behave greedily and egregiously and ruin whatever it is you are trying to accomplish. That being said you have no way of accounting for low moral and ethical standards in your code.  Good luck.

Comment: @amdopt: I tried to register but couldnt so I had to use my account from other stackexhange sites. I am the same person. Sorry about that! But would you say that you use predictive analytics to "predict" price movements? I know that firms like RenTech use "big data" (e.g. weather, tweets, etc.) to find patterns in price movements.

Comment: @PEV Yes, I use some predictive analyses.  I also use some that are reactive.  My comment is more cautionary than anything.  Giving traders access to other traders info is very dangerous.  You will see a level of behavior within your firm that you would have never thought possible when you began this endeavor.  Patterns in prices mean nothing when behavioral patterns are being manipulated by divulging data that would have otherwise never been divulged.

Comment: @PEV you can [merge your accounts](https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @amdopt: Traders in real life won't literally have access to the actions of other traders. I am just saying that is trader looks at the general price behavior of a particular asset, this might influence his current decision as to whether to buy, sell, or stay out of the market.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for comments about a code and do not explain the methodology / algorithm a formal way using English and maths.